# No internet even with iptables ACCEPT all

Tags: centos, iptables, firewall

I was trying to setup the firewall settings, and probably did something wrong. I don't have internet now unless I stop `iptables` service

I tried flushing,and accepting everything

```
sudo iptables -F
sudo iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
sudo iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
```

But I still cannot access internet. if I stop the service,

```
sudo service iptables stop
```

then I can access inet. Starting again blocks it.

Can you point me where the problem lies?

(I'm running CentOS 6.4)

Comment: `iptables -L` what gives?

Comment: `iptables` has several other tables, try `iptables -t nat -S`, `iptables -t mangle -S`, `iptables -t raw -S`.

Comment: I played with the firewall settings as the other answer suggested, and now it works. I got something somewhere got changed, and now its good.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `iptables` command per default only shows entries of the filter table.

But there are also other tables:

[image]

There are probably some entries in the nat table. Add `-t nat` to your commands to look at them.